# When presenting text, occurrences of "1/2" are changed to "½" (vulgar fraction one half), how do I prevent that?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uilabel

I have this thing in my app driving me nuts.

In my current project I show dates localized and the problem is that occurrences of "1/2" is changed to ½, which renders like this:

[image: Vulgar Fraction One Half in UILabel]

The `dateText` is exactly what is set to `text` on the `UILabel`.

When digging deeper I saw this in Safari as well:

[image: Vulgar Fraction One Half in Safari]
*To the left is Safari and to the right the text in the database*

I see this behavior in both the simulator and on the phone.

Can someone please tell me what is going on?

Comment: What is the font? This is more likely caused by font ligatures.

Comment: A custom font. You are spot on, the custom font is the culprit. Add an answer and I will accept it as correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably caused by your font.

Fonts have a feature called [ligatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature) which basically replace a predefined set of characters by a single glyph.

Note that you should be able to turn ligatures off using `NSAttributeString` (attribute [NSAttributedString.Key.ligature](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/key/1524592-ligature)).

In Safari, it can be turned off using CSS property [font-feature-settings](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/font-feature-settings/)

Comment: Perfect answer, you answered my next question as well, "can I turn it off".